# Nativescript + Vue: sync only works the first time on both device and emulator

Tags: android, ios, nativescript-vue

Project Nativescript + Vue

NativeScript CLI version: 5.4.2

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "2.3.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "6.4.2",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.2.2",
    "nativescript-vue-navigator": "0.0.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.4.3",
    "vuex": "3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.6",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.1"
  },
```

When I build and run "tns run" or "tns debug" or use "Run on device" on Sidekick, the syncronization on both device and emulator only works the first time.
From the second time I get blank screen or get the error:

> Calling js method onCreateView failed
>
> Error: View already has a parent. View: Page(23) Parent:
>   TabViewItem(22)

I've already tried to disable Hot Module Replacement but the problem continue.
The only solution is to uninstall the app and rerun the local build.

**The problem occours on both local and cloud build.**

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding `--bundle`?

Comment: Yeah... even with ```--bundle``` I get the same error. I think it's something related to **Navigator** or **TabViewItem** becouse if I stay in login screen, reload happens without any problem. Anyway I've updated the question with the complete error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I refactored my application ising NS6 and now it works well!